# Using the logical operator 'AND' in the query builder

Tags: qgis, layers, query

I am trying to use the query builder to select numerous features in a layer.

I saw a question on here that suggests using the AND operator to do this. however, I have this to no avail.

My query returns no selected roads (see image).

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: This dialogue is from the filter expression, are you  looking for select by query instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you would want `OR` instead of `AND`.

If you read the expression back to yourself you can see that "when the legend equals dual carriageway and legend equals single carriageway" is impossible since the same field cannot have two different values at once, while with OR it sounds plausible.